# Queue the AWS lambda function calls

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 3 AWS Lambda functions and a web app interface where I can invoke those lambda functions using AWS SDK. I have a requirement that if one lambda function is executing and I invoked the other lambda function while the first one is under processing, I want to queue the lambda function call so that another lambda will be executed only the first one is finished executing.

Comment: I think you may need to give some more details about the requirement... it could be achieved with some kind of resource lock e.g. check for an object in an S3 bucket, but without a better understanding of the requirement, this may not be what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but maybe you can take a look at AWS Step Functions providing a state machine to synchronize Lambda processing: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions